# Using Liquibase to create procedures

Tags: sql, plsql, liquibase

I'm evaluating [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) for a project starting today.

Has anybody used it  to create procedures, functions, basically all of the plsql stuff?

If not, is it possible to write embedded sql code in the xml files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a built-in [createProcedure](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/create_procedure.html) tag in liquibase for managing procedures.  The best approach is usually to combine the  or  tags with runOnChange so liquibase will update your procedure when and only when you update the definition.  That way you can do diffs between your changelog xml files over time and see how the procedure has changed.

Using the [sqlFile](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html) tag to reference file per stored-proc is also popular, or, like you said, you can use the [sql](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) tag to inline custom sql.

Comment: I'm everywhere :) LMK if you run into any other questions or problems, or need more clarification

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered issues with trying the use the sql tag for stored procedures, triggers, and functions, but in my case these were provably issues with the MySQL JDBC driver, and not Liquibase itself. The practice I've settled into is to use the sqlFile refactoring as Nathan suggests, then to control the SP/trigger/function code in the same project as the changelog, versioned in the source code system along with it. This lets you manage the SP/whatever code just like it was real source code.

Setting runOnChange="true" in the changeSet containing the sqlFile refactoring is essential. It is this switch (thank you, Nathan) that enables real source control of procedural database code.

Comment: Hey Tim, so if I get the gist of it, would it be logical to have a {schemaName}/sprocs/ populated with sproc_name.xml files and then have Liquibase detect and update the schema when these file's are updated?

Comment: That would work, but I think it would be a little bulky. What I've done is have a single "stored-proc.xml" (or something) changelog, which has the runOnChange="true" changeSets in it, each running a single idempotent, SP-creating SQL script located at db/src/procs/*.sql (or somewhere). As long as you update that changelog every time the SP code might change, you'll always have up-to-date SPs in the database and in source control. When you add a new SP, add a new changeSet to that changelog. Works great!

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't used liquibase for stored procedures, I have some experience of Liquibase for more generic operations.

It is possible to write custom sql, either embedded in the xml file or referenced from an external file.